# Which is better performance wise, C# for loop or cursor(or while loop) in sql?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Which will perform better while loop or cursor? 
After lots of research, I came to know they both are equally bad for performance and may sometime out perform each other based on situation, and should be used only when it is not possible to use set based operation.

Now question is Which is better performance wise, loop in C# or cursor(or while loop) in sql?
and I searched in web, but found no definitive result...

anybody have any idea?

Comment: How can you even compare c# for loop with a cursor?

Comment: now I am implement code inside cursor in c#, it may take some time to complete it. Once completed I'll let u know...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on my experience I would say: it depends on which operations you perform on every item...

In a scenario it happened to me to use cursor loop in SQL for performing bit-wise operation on some data read from the DB and it was very poor in performance (SQL is not intended to operate such kind of stuff)... in that case I obtained a better result looping in C# on a cursor opened on the DB...

On the other side, if you have to perform some other complex data-mining task for every item of the loop, then it is much more convenient to do that in SQL, so that your data do not have to go back and forth from DB to C# and viceversa.

Have you a specific application scenario you can talk about, so that we can give you an idea about that?

Comment: It is actually a warehouse situation. we are comparing order placed by customer and comparing it inventory based on that there are some complex procedure happens. This is our scenario.

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing: if my understandings are correct, for every item of your loop you will then execute several other SQL queries for to compare the order with the inventory... am I right? In such a scenario I would prefer an approach SQL-based and then I will tend to implement everything in a stored procedure containing a cursor loop in SQL... I hope you find useful my suggestion: if so, please mark my answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "a for loop in C#", do you mean that you intend to first load all the results from the query, and then subsequently loop over them? The downside of that approach is of course that you need the memory to hold all those results. But you don't have to do that. There are many mechanisms in C# that allow you to loop over the results *as they come in*, which avoids the need to hold all results in memory. It depends of course on your database access technology.

If you use some technology based on `IQueryable<T>`, just use a `foreach` loop over the result, and avoid calling materialization functions on it, such as `.ToList()`.

As for cursors, always avoid them if possible. For performance, always prefer set based operations over cursors. In fact, the same is true for a foreach loop in C#. If your processing of each result involves querying the database again, use a SQL join that returns you the needed data in a single query, instead of a new query for each result row retrieved.